# RealmModel implenting classes require fields to be used through getter / setter only?

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm implementing my single logged in user through Realm. Every time an API call returns me a user object, I save the user into the DB using something like this:

```
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.createOrUpdateObjectFromJson(UserModel.class,jsonObject);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

I have a central function called `loadUser()` which loads up the saved object like so:

```
private void loadUser(){
    currentUser = realm.where(UserModel.class).findFirst();
}
```

Where `currentUser` is obviously a member variable in my singleton.

This was working fine and dandy, until the point of time when I tried to refer to an object property. I'm pretty much using the `RealmModel` implementing `UserModel` class like a POJO but have wired up intelligent methods that return intelligent values for things like avatars, etc. I started noticing that the generated `UserModelProxy` object *does not* have the values set when I inspect it in Debug mode, even though the database does, when I open it and browse it on OSX using RealmBrowser app.

- I can see the values in the DB.
- I can't see the values in debugger.
- My `if` conditions fail when I try to use the values directly.

I just changed all my code to making the fields `private`, and using them through generated getter and setter functions, which just directly accessing the variables. And those work!

Did I do something wrong, or does the realm java documentation fail to mention that I **need** to generate getter and setter functions that their generated Proxy classes will override?

Comment: This entirely depends on what Realm version you're using, so you should kinda specify what version of Realm you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the latest version of Realm (2.2.0) and after some more code debugging, it turns out that I was wrong, the problem was with **my** if condition, not with Realm database.

I guess it *does* make some sense to use getters/setters, though. Whatever magic Realm does with the generated proxy model classes, it doesn't translate through to inspection in the debugger. Knowing that we're supposed to use the getter and setter lets us get the correct values when we inspect in the Android Studio debugger also.

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#android-studio-debugging even with field access, adding a watcher for `realm$getId()` would return the proper values. But I do think that using setter/getter is more stable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use accessors, because Realm uses native implementation and it proxies those values by those accessors. see this https://realm.io/docs/java/0.79.0/api/io/realm/RealmObject.html. 
"Annotation processor will create a proxy class for your RealmObject subclass. The getters and setters should not contain any custom code of logic as they are overridden as part of the annotation process."

Comment: `The getters and setters should not contain any custom code of logic` Hold on, that limitation was lifted in 0.88.0 with the Gradle plugin and the Realm-Transformer, about a year ago or so. You **can** have custom logic in getter/setter since 0.88.0.

Comment: Maybe that's true, but custom logic in accessors mean poor design. I prefer using realm objects only in part, responsible for interaction with db and convert result in another model object

Comment: Meh, I wouldn't want to do a `Observable.from(results).flatMap((element) -> return mapper.mapFromRealm(element)).toList()`, because then I lose lazy evaluation of result sets and automatic updates. Also, custom setter logic is good for the creation of "computed properties".